# What is my report manager username/password? How to find it out?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services, reportmanager

I have SQL Server 2008 with BIDS, I have installed sql server myself and i am administrator of machine. Now I am able to make reports using BIDS, I am also able to login(windows authentication) to report server using SSMS, but when i try to access report manager URL it asks me for Username/passowrd. I am not sure what to give there as till now from SSMS i could manage with windows authentication for  database engine.

Comment: Are you getting the authentication screen while accessing through browser other than IE ?

Comment: @praveen It asks me for credential in IE/Chrome both?

Comment: Go to the RSReportServer.config file and add basic Authentication .The file will be stored in the location <Installation directory> \Reporting Services \ReportServer. for detailed explanation go the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866

Comment: In my system the report server config file is present in the location C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\ReportingService\ReportServer folder and to change the config file refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx

Answer (score 6):

SSRS always uses Windows authentication so your user name and password that you're seeing is your Windows login. There is no separate account just for Report Manager. If you're seeing a prompt, you might have UAC enabled and it's prompting you because of that. Or your browser is not enabled for Windows integrated security. You can add the Report Manager URL to trusted sites or Intranet sites if you're using IE.